# Number of hits in activities search field

Tags: gnome, wayland

I have created seven .desktop files for a task XYZ. All files contain "XYZ" as a keyword in the "Keywords=" field. My idea was that I could show these .desktop files by clicking on "Activities" and entering "XYZ" in the search field.  The only problem is that only a maximum of 6 search hits appear when "XYZ" is entered. Is the number of search hits limited to 6? Is this a desired behaviour? Is it a feature or a bug?

I would like to adjust the limit on the number of search hits displayed. Is this possible? Does anyone know anything about this?

My environment *Ubuntu Version 22.04*:

```
:~$ printenv | grep XDG
XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=ubuntu
XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu:GNOME
:~$
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a bug. The number of search hits is limited to 6 as a way to prevent the search results from becoming overwhelming. This is a desirable behaviour, as it keeps the search results manageable and easy to understand.

Unfortunately, it is not possible to change the limit on the number of search hits displayed.
The only way to do that is modifying the configuration files that are typically located in the **~/.config/** directory and this could be quite complex to do if you do not have a clear understanding. You can refer to the documentation if you want to make any changes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Vic. Do you have any idea what the configuration settings file in the ~/.config/ folder is called? Or do you have for me a link to a source where I can inform myself about the appropriate configuration settings for the display of search results?

Comment: yeah, you can refer to the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1024114/location-of-ini-config-files-in-linux-unix